# Prevent header and footer from loading on specific pages with template or plugin

Tags: php, hooks, templates, page-template

I am working on a client's site that has a few pages that are embedded into a mobile app through WebView.  The goal is to prevent the header and footer from showing up on these certain pages.  I can't remove the `get_header()` function because I still need the styling and Javascript in the `<head>` element.  I just don't want the actual `<header>` element to appear.  Currently my solution for this problem is a template that adds a CSS `display: none` snippet on the `<header>`, but I'd like to save resources by preventing the header source from even loading (through PHP).  I understand that I can edit the theme files and just add a conditional to the `header.php` file.  However, this issue has come up with multiple clients and therefore I need a way that can carry over to multiple different sites with the same theme, whether that's through a template or a plugin.

Comment: This might be helpful if you're looking for programmatic solutions: https://medium.com/swlh/bring-your-wordpress-to-your-android-app-using-the-wordpress-rest-api-and-webviews-af65a68f1606. Otherwise I think you're stuck with page templates and conditionals.

Comment: In my opinion, the easiest and best way to solve this is via a child theme. Add a child theme and add an empty header and footer file (or with some conditionals) and then let WordPress grab the empty child template files while the rest gets used from the parent theme.

Comment: @Pixelsmith Thank you!  I may end up using that - the only downside is that my team uses a graphical app builder (not my choice) that I doubt has the ability to make direct API requests.

Comment: @user3135691 That sounds much like what I'm looking for - thanks for the advice!  I'll look into it.